# Join query for two documents in cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

In Cosmos DB two documents:

1. first_document (List type)
2. second_document

First query to get data from first_document passing "abcd" as param

input param: abcd

Query 1:

```sql
select  c.first_name, c.second_name
from c
IN t.first_document
where c.first_document_code = abcd
```

Second query takes first_name from above query as input param.

Query 2:

```sql
select *
from c.second_document
where c.second_document_code = "first_name"
```

this 2nd query will return list as response.

how to join these queries into single query?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, join these queries is not supported. You can only query twice to get what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

According to Azure's documentation, documents that reference other documents is not recommended.

> In Azure Cosmos DB for NoSQL, data is schema-free and typically denormalized. Instead of joining data across entities and sets, like you would in a relational database, joins occur within a single item. Specifically, joins are scoped to that item and can't occur across multiple items and containers. If you find yourself needing to join across items and containers, consider reworking your [data model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data) to avoid this.

Source: [Self-joins in Azure Cosmos DB for NoSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/join)